# What algorithm can I implement to find all legal jumps for a pawn in checkers?

Tags: algorithm

I started creating a checkers game in python but I can't imagine an algorithm that could find all playable moves for a selected pawn.

For the moment, I have already created the algorithm which makes it possible to find the empty squares adjacent to the selected pawn and to add them to the list of playable moves. On the other hand, I can't imagine the algorithm that would make it possible to find all the playable "jumps" for a selected pawn.

Thus, for a selected pawn, the program must:

- check if there is a pawn located to the north + 1 west + 1 tile of the selected pawn
- check if the color of this pawn is different from the color of the selected pawn
- check if the tile located north + 2 west + 2 is empty
- add the coordinates of the tiles to the list of playable tiles if all the previous conditions are considered true

But then, the program will have to look if another jump is possible from this new coordinate, moreover, for each legal coordinate found, the program will have to look each time north west and north east.

I've tried to find answers on the internet but other than other people's projects on github which I'm having a lot of trouble understanding, I can't find anything.

Can I adapt a known algorithm to find all these legal jumps and if so what algorithm is it? Thanks to which programming concept could I implement this algorithm?

Comment: If you have already implemented the single move algorithm, you can just use it recursively. If you are worried about the depth, I don't think it will be a problem on an 8x8 board. And since you need to find all legal jumps anyway, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: What kind of data structure are you using on it?

Comment: @Berthur by recursively do you mean calling the function itself with new coordinates?

Comment: @Filipizaum I use a matrix to represent the checkerboard in which I stored None if the square is empty or a pawn object if there is a pawn on the square.

Comment: @Karichi Yes, so you find your legal moves and then for each legal move you check if there are further legal moves from there. The trick is keeping track of all paths you found so far. It should essentially be a binary tree, and you need to find all paths from the root (current position).

Comment: Why do you want to find all possible paths? If you want to calculate for the player, wouldn't they make their moves one step at the time, and continue their turn until no more steps are possible? If you want to calculate for the AI, wouldn't you just want to find the best possible sequence?

Comment: @VLL I would like indicators to appear on all playable squares when a player clicks on a pawn and for the moment, I do not plan to implement artificial intelligence.

Comment: @Karichi Notice that the destination square does not always uniquely identify a move. Sometimes you can jump left then right, or right then left, and end up on the same square. Yet the difference can be strategically important.

Comment: @Karichi What I've seen other Checkers applications do is to show only the 1st-level moves, then if you drag or slide your pawn to those squares, it highlights the next level moves etc. So you drag in zig-zag, and when you drop the mouse/finger, the move is done. Quite intuitive and easier to implement..

Comment: @Berthur I hadn't thought of that, it might actually be a good approach.